# A public action method 'X' was not found on controller 'Y' producing a 404 error

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I have searched other threads with this issue and none of them seemed to be of any use.

I am attempting to add a page to my MVC application which I have done many times in the past but I am receiving a `404` error when trying to access this new page.

On the controller I have:

```
[Helpers.Attributes.ExistingUser]       
public ActionResult X()
{
    return View();
}
```

I then right clicked and selected Add View...

My view page is very standard right now with just the following code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "X";
}

<h2>X</h2>
```

On a separate page I have a HTML link as follows to go to page X:

```
<a href="/Application/Y/X" class="master-button" style="display:block;float:left;">X</a>
```

I have this exact same setup on other pages and they are working just fine. Am I missing something when I was creating this page?

Comment: You haven't provided all the code to debug this.  We need to see the controller name.  Additionally we need to see all the routes.

Comment: Try this instead: <a href='@Url.Action("X", "Y")' class="master-button" style="display:block;float:left;">X</a>

Comment: Sahil, while your code does work to create a link to the page it is still coming up as not being found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some collaboration with fellow IT. The solution was that the code needed to be cleaned and rebuilt and then the new page was finally recognized in the controller.